# Count removes all but one value, instead of showing one of each value, and distinct replaces names with '0'

Tags: mysql

I want to show how many films each actor has played (sakila db on MySQL)

```
select distinct (a.first_name + ' ' + a.last_name as "Actor Full Name"),
       count(distinct(fa.film_id))
from actor a join film_actor fa
on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get `0` as name is because you are using the operator `+` to concatenate strings, but this is not the concatenation operator in MySql. It is the numeric addition operator, so the strings are implicitly converted to the number `0` and the result is also `0`.

To concatenate strings in MySql you must use either the function `CONCAT()` or the function `WS_CONCAT()`.

Also, you must group by actor:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', a.first_name, a.last_name) AS `Actor Full Name`,
       COUNT(*) AS `Number Of Films`
FROM actor a JOIN film_actor f
ON a.actor_id = f.actor_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id;
```

I assume that `actor_id` is the primary key of the table `actor`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&sample=sakila&fiddle=a2ac884bef7e3a0359f4adb485a89908).